# Wordpress doesn't see my new style.css file

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add new stylesheet to wordpress, I'm adding via functions where are all old .css files and they are working. So when I add new file, wordpress doesn't see it and when I click on file link from view source, I get 404 error, but that file is in identical folder and has identical link as all old working .css files just with different name.
I tried to clean cache, update permalinks, but problem still the same.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/custom/assets/css/customname.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/custom/assets/css/news-internal.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/custom/assets/css/skinprofile.css"/>
```

So *news-internal.css* and *skinprofile.css* is working and *customname.css* links to 404 error..
What I'm missing? What can I try to change?

Comment: Are you using child theme?

Comment: I'm using thesis_185 theme, but with a lot of custom changes. How theme can affect new files, but not the old ones if I import them identically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my filezilla client, my file was failed to upload, but I could see it.
I uploaded it again and after that I could reach my .css file with link.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to include a style via "bloginfo()". Try

```
function name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bs/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bsscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'antoher-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bs/js/eschadl.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'name_scripts' );
```

so

```
function name_scripts() { ... } => Name of your Function, e.g. mytemplate_scripts()

wp_enqueue_style(); => for CSS-Files

wp_enqueue_scriptJS(); => for CSS-Files
```

So between your braces u have to notice:

```
'bs' => Name of your Style-Sheet you want. It can be different to the real name of the file
get_template_directory_uri() => same like bloginfo()
afterward(!) ". '/style.css' => . is connector between url and your file
```

So the URL look like

```
http://www.yourwebsite.de/style.css
```

And in your Wordpress

```
http://www.yourwebsite.de/wp-content/themes/themesname/style.css
```

If your file in another direction you have to modify the path after the point (" . ")

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/order1/order2/file.min.css');
```

So in your Wordpress it looks like

```
http://www.yourwebsite.de/wp-content/themes/themesname/order1/order2/file.min.css
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to view source and check you css file "customname.css" is listed or not. If that file is shown in view source then click the link of that file an still get the 404 there too. Then first check the name of file "customname.css" with filename inside folder. Then check the whole path by comparing view source path and your directory structure. Still getting the same issue then check are you using the child theme or simple theme?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/custom/assets/css/customname.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/custom/assets/css/news-internal.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/custom/assets/css/skinprofile.css"/>
```